# Python coverage: excluding files

Tags: python, unit-testing, config, code-coverage

I am using *unittest2* with *coverage* within a virtual environment which also contains my project.

When I run `coverage report -m`, the report shows several other files from *lib/python3.5/site-packages/*.

Because there are several files to exclude, it is tedious to try to exclude them from the command line each time I want to run the test and see the coverage report. That is why I choose to rely on the configuration file instead.

The [documentation](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/config.html) says I should do so in the ***.coveragerc*** file. However I can not see it. When I run `pip show coverage` and then `ls -a path_to_coverage_directory` I see `config.py` file instead. So excluded one file from testing and reporting from it by looking where is the option `--omit` and [changed it](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/source.html#source) from:

```
self._omit = None
```

to:

```
self._omit = ['/home/begueradj/development/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/unittest2/case.py']
```

I saved the configuration file and run the test as well as the coverage report again: I saw this file is not excluded.

What am I missing? How do you tackle with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.coveragerc` is a file in your project's local directory that indicates how coverage should treat that specific set of code. You should have something like the following:

```
myproject/
 - mycodefile1.py
 - mycodefile2.py
 - ...
 - .coveragerc
```

Where `.coveragerc` is in the directory where you're executing `coverage` and `unittest` from. It contains the following:

```
[run]
omit = 
    case.py
```

or maybe something like:

```
[run]
source = mycodefile*.py
```

You can combine `source` and `omit` to include entire directories of code while excluding specific files within those directories. All depends on what exactly your code layout looks like. See here for [how you can specify code files](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1x/source.html#source).